# VM execution error at contract simulation UMA LSP contract

Tags: deployment, virtual-machine, liskov-substitution-principle, kovan

I am trying to deploy a smart contract on Kovan testnet with the UMA protocol. More specifically following this tutorial: https://docs.umaproject.org/developers/deploy-an-lsp

I am running the deployment script with the following parameters:

```
node index.js 
--gasprice 15 
--url wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/PROJECTIDInfura
--mnemonic "SEED PHRASE"
--pairName "WHTUSDJune" 
--expirationTimestamp 1655312460 
--collateralPerPair 1000000000 
--priceIdentifier BTCUSD 
--longSynthName "wheat_SRW_June_long" 
--longSynthSymbol WHTUSDBJun 
--shortSynthName "wheat_SRW_June_short" 
--shortSynthSymbol WHTUSDSJun 
--collateralToken 0x7079f3762805cff9c979a5bdc6f5648bcfee76c8 
--fpl Linear 
--lowerBound 0 
--upperBound 2000000000 
--proposerReward 2000000 
--optimisticOracleProposerBond 200000000
```

But this is the error I get at contract simulation:

```
Error: VM execution error.
    at WebsocketSubprovider._handleSocketMessage (C:\Users\FOLDER\launch-lsp\node_modules\@trufflesuite\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\websocket.js:121:18)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\FOLDER\launch-lsp\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\FOLDER\launch-lsp\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:720:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\FOLDER\launch-lsp\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:414:14)
    at C:\Users\FOLDER\launch-lsp\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:371:23
    at C:\Users\FOLDER\launch-lsp\node_modules\ws\lib\permessage-deflate.js:307:9
    at C:\Users\FOLDER\launch-lsp\node_modules\ws\lib\permessage-deflate.js:389:7
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:468:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:448:7)
    at InflateRaw.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:98:3)
    at Zlib.processCallback (zlib.js:580:8)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found out which parameter was making my request crash. It is:

```
--priceIdentifier BTCUSD
```

I replaced it with

```
--priceIdentifier UMAUSD
```

and it worked like a charm. Not sure why as BTCUSD is listed as a price identfier on their site.